# Move evaluation on armageddon games

Tags: stockfish, evaluation

I am wondering if there is a Stockfish-like evaluation of moves that could take in account armageddon rules, the rules being that you lose if you draw.

I would imagine a strategy of just trading everything off symmetrically would be completely reasonable in a regular game but in armadeddon you lose on a draw, so you have to try something differently.

The same ideas apply to some openings which are likely to give drawish results.

Comment: I shred your question on r/ComputerChess, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ComputerChess/comments/gwxwnf/move_evaluation_on_armageddon_games_i_found_this/fsy2cz8?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) seems a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the contempt factor really high in an engine it will likely be able to play armageddon. Contempt factor is how much it accepts (or doesn't accept) draws. If contempt is high enough it should view a draw just as bad as losing.

https://www.chessprogramming.org/Contempt_Factor is a good article to read on contempt factor if you're unaware of the concept.